# Gradle Error: Android Studio, ActionbarSherlock, and SlidingMenu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, slidingmenu

I've been at this for a couple of days trying to get the library structure correct within Android Studio. I would have just continued with Eclipse, but performance wise, it's been really bad for me lately. Please, any guidance would be greatly appreciated as all solutions found have not worked and the documentation has lead me nowhere.

All manifests have an empty application tag except for the main TestProject.

Edit* Prior to including SlidingMenu, I did have ActionBarSherlock working without issues and building, etc.

### The Error

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libraries:SlidingMenu:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

#### Build.Gradle (SlidingMenu)

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
}

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
        compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'


sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aild.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

#### Build.Gradle (ActionBarSherlock)

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

#### Build.Gradle (Test Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

#### settings.gradle (Test Project)

```
include ':TestProject',':libraries:actionbarsherlock',':libraries:SlidingMenu'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this could be happening for a lot of reasons. I'd suggest running `gradle build -info` from the command line to see if it gives you more information.

A common merge failure I've run into is when the minSdkVersions are conflicting. I see that your test project minSdkVersion is 7, are the minimum levels declared in the ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu manifests 7 or less?

Comment: Good eye, I had just found out about running gradlew projectDebug. I took care of the manifest issues which were definitely minSdkVerion mismatch, now it can't find the JDK. :D Problems, problems.

Comment: I'll mark yours as a solution, as it was, and now the new problem is probably best to be left to a new thread.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was with 'missing `<application/>` tag' in slidingmenu library.
After adding empty `<application/>` tag to manifest errors disappeared.
Maybe this will help somebody.

See thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/PIah7eYXiNs

Answer (score 4):

I already solve it. I share my configuration. Maybe this can help you.

**Project:**

```
+ TestProject
|-- libraries
   |-- ActionBarSherlock
       |-- actionbarsherlock
       |-- actionbarsherlock-fest
       |-- actionbarsherlock-i18n
       |-- actionbarsherlock-samples
   |-- SlidingMenu
       |-- art
       |-- example
       |-- library
       |-- library-maps-support
|-- TestProject
```

**setting.gradle**

```
include ':TestProject', ':libraries:SlidingMenu:library', ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock'
```

**build.gradle (Test Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu:library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (actionbarsherlock lib)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (slidingmenu lib)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this is a lost cause. I have to go back to Eclipse (Wasted too much time already). The issue is that the errors are not consistent or reproducible. I've remade new projects from scratch reproducing my exact same steps, 4 times, and hit a different dead end each time. Something is wrong internally that I cannot view with stacktrace, debug, or info.

Comment: @Christian : thanks man, you saved my life! Your solution works perfectly to build ActionBarSherlock with gradle in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Why must you have sourceSets block in ABS build.gradle file?